# How to consolidate JS functions into one function utilizing event.target?

Tags: javascript

I have a div with 12 buttons. Each one has eventListeners for mouseenter(). When user rolls over a button, the other 11 buttons fade out. I've got enough code to make your eyes bleed. But I'm having trouble consolidating it all into one function, and just using event.target.

I can get the basics going, but am having problems inserting a for loop (with a continue needed, I believe) to fade out each of the other buttons, not including the one that is being hovered over (my event.target element). You can see in my code, that currently I have a line of code for each of the other buttons, to run an opacity fade loop on them. How can I consolidate this into a single function?

Here is the code I'm running each time a button gets rolled over:

```
function fadeOut01() {
var op = 1;  // initial opacity
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op <= 0.1){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    box02.style.opacity = op;
    box03.style.opacity = op;
    box04.style.opacity = op;
    box05.style.opacity = op;
    box06.style.opacity = op;
    box07.style.opacity = op;
    box08.style.opacity = op;
    box09.style.opacity = op;
    box10.style.opacity = op;
    box11.style.opacity = op;
    box12.style.opacity = op;
    op -= op * 0.1;
}, 20);
}
```

And here is the html where I define the boxes:

```
<a href="ffvideo.html"><div id="grid01" class="grids"><div class="gridText">video</div></div></a>
        <a href="ffbroadcast.html"><div id="grid02" class="grids"><div class="gridText">broadcast</div></div></a>
        <a href="ffgraphics.html"><div id="grid03" class="grids"><div class="gridText">graphics</div></div></a>
        <a href="ffsignage.html"><div id="grid04" class="grids"><div class="gridText">digital signage</div></div></a>
        <div id="grid05" class="grids"><div class="gridText">3d</div></div>
        <div id="grid06" class="grids"><div class="gridText">virtual sets</div></div>
        <div id="grid07" class="grids"><div class="gridText">print</div></div>
        <div id="grid08" class="grids"><div class="gridText">technical direction</div></div>
        <div id="grid09" class="grids"><div class="gridText">live events</div></div>
        <div id="grid10" class="grids"><div class="gridText">photography</div></div>
        <div id="grid11" class="grids"><div class="gridText">workflow automation</div></div>
        <a href="fflogos.html"><div id="grid12" class="grids"><div class="gridText">our clients</div></div></a>
```

Comment: What is `box02`, `box03`, etc? Sounds like you should use classes instead

Comment: box02, 03, etc. are the other 11 buttons/boxes. They all fade away when user hovers over 1 box.  You can see it at www.finleyfilms.com.

Comment: Does this even need JavaScript? Can't you do it all in CSS?

Comment: I guess my issue (besides being new to this, and self-trained) is that I don't know how to deal with accessing "all the other objects of this class, except the one that the mouse is hovering over". Any ideas?

Comment: Again, please post where you define all the boxes

Comment: modified my original post to include the html where i define the boxes.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be solvable via the following - please see the comments below for contextualized information on how this works:

```js
/* Query all grids of the grid-wrapper and apply same hover behavior to each */
document.querySelectorAll('.grid-wrapper .grids').forEach(function(element) {

  /* Get the grid wrapper that encloses the grid element */
  const gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.grid-wrapper');

  /* Add mouse over event and add hover classes for both the wrapper and 
  grid elements */
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

    element.classList.add('hover');
    gridWrapper.classList.add('hover');
  });

  /* Add mouse out event and remove hover classes for both the wrapper and 
  grid elements */
  element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {

    element.classList.remove('hover');
    gridWrapper.classList.remove('hover');
  });

});
```

```css
.grid-wrapper .grids {
  
  /* Set default opacity for grid-wrapper grids */
  opacity: 1;
  
  /* Specifcy the transition behavior for opacity property of .grids.
  Transition will take .35s and be delayed by .1s to reduce flickering 
  when moving quickly between grids */
  transition: opacity 0.35s linear 0.1s;
  
  /* Extra styles just added for presentation */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}

/* When .hover modifier class is applied to the wrapper, cause the 
children (.grids) to fade out by default (we'll prevent/override this
default behavior for the actual grid child being hovered to achieve 
the desired final result) */
.grid-wrapper.hover .grids {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

/* Override the default grid-wrapper hover for the actual grid being
hovered to ensure
that it is still visible */
.grid-wrapper.hover .grids.hover {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div id="grid01" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">video</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid02" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">broadcast</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid03" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">graphics</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid04" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">digital signage</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid05" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">3d</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid06" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">virtual sets</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid07" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">print</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid08" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">technical direction</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid09" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">live events</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid10" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">photography</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid11" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">workflow automation</div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid12" class="grids">
    <div class="gridText">our clients</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess I'm still not seeing where the logic is of "fade all the other buttons, but not this one being hovered on". If I just change a className or run a CSS transition, it will fade all the boxes. I want to keep the one being hovered on, at full opacity.

Comment: Assuming I understand your question correctly, the idea the `.grids:hover` selector is that the `:hover` part basically means "when something with class `grids` is hovered, apply these style changes" (ie a modified `opacity`). Because a `transition` has been defined for the `opacity` property (ie in `.grids`), this will cause a transition to occur on the `opacity` property over time, whenever a change to the `opacity` value is detected. Hope that helps clarify this a little more

Comment: Thanks. I’m good with all that, but I don’t want to fade out all elements of class “grids” I want to fade out all of the other elements, except for the one being hovered on. Apologize if I’m being dense here and missing something.

Comment: Hey, no need to apologize :-) . Ok - is this a correct summary:

You want all elements that are not ".grids" to be initially faded out. When any element that is not a ".grids" is hovered over, it fades in, and if hovered out, it fades out. And, at all times ".grids" are always visible, regardless of whether they are hovered or not. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok not quite. I start with 12 boxes on screen. User can hover over box 7 (for example) and then all 11 other boxes fade to transparent. User rolls off of box 7, and then all 11 other boxes fade back up to full opacity, so we are back to how we start, with 12 boxes all fully visible.  Make sense? If you're at a computer, it is live on my site at www.finleyfilms.com. Just move the mouse slowly ;)

Comment: @warlock7 sorry for the delay coming back to you - ah, ok, think I've got you now :-) Just updated answer. Does that help?